# Square root of $I - AA^t$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times M}$ be full-rank, and such that $I - AA^t$ is positive semi-definite.

Then there exists a matrix $S$ such that $S^2 = I - AA^t$, and $S$ is symmetric and positive semi-definite.

Is there an efficient way of finding $S$, say from some factorization of $A$?

Comment: I am no specialist, but I doubt it. Even in the scalar case, there is no shortcut to $\sqrt{1-a^2}$.

Comment: If $M\ll N$, there might be a shortcut